# Having trouble getting the Id of last inserted PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I am trying to use php to insert an object into a MySql table and then get the Id of the newly created object but i can not figure out why it is not working. Here is what i have:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `".$Table."` (`ID`) VALUES (NULL);";
$resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

$query = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @".$Table.";";
$resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

echo mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset);
```

The insert works great but I am just getting an empty value where I should be getting the Id. Thanks!

New Code:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `".$Table."` (`ID`) VALUES (NULL); ";
$resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);
$id = mysql_insert_id();

echo $id;
```

Comment: use mysql_insert_id(). caheck an tell

Comment: This is one of the reasons why I strongly suggest using `mysqli()` or `PDO()` instead of deprecated `mysql_*`. With mysqli you have `$mysqli->insert_id` and with PDO you have `$pdo->lastInsertId()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after executing first query you have to use the function that i tell you:-

```
$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

And then change your second query LAST_INSERT_ID() to $id.

Note:- please take care of double and single quote at the time using $id in second query.

Also mysql_* is officially deprecated now. Use mysqli_* or PDO for this purpose.

Comment: If I had multiple people inserting objects from different computers would it ever get screwed up? For instance computer A inserts with Id 1 and computer two inserts with Id 2 at practically the same time would computer A always say the Id is 1?

Comment: Yup. If your coding is correct then it never gonna mess-up. no matter how many users and how much data and how much time difference between entries inserted.

Comment: Ok can you please see the edit to make sure I did it exactly right

Comment: Just run your query. if it give you correct result then it's correct. Don't ask to please check,check yourself and insure yourself.

Comment: Well yeah I checked it myself but you emphasized exactly right

Comment: It seems quite ok. no problem

Answer (score 2):

This SQL query:

```
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @Something;
```

doesn't return a resultset. (It does set the variable.) So, your fetch_assoc statement doesn't get anything back.

If you want the id in the resultset do this.

```
 SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Or, use the mysql_insert_id() function.